# How to read path from a txt file and copy those file to a new directory?

Tags: python, file-io, copy

> ```
> from shutil import  copy
> f = open(r'C:\temp.txt', 'r')
> for i in f.readlines():
>     print i
>     copy(i,r"C:\opencascade")    
>
> f.close()
> ```

I am reading path from temp.txt file which has 500 lines each line is a path for specific file to be copied to location "C:\opencascade"
How to convert 'i' in above code to be raw string to make the code work

Error from interpreter

```
    copy(i,r"C:\opencascade")    
  File "C:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 88, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\shutil.py", line 52, in copyfile
    fsrc = open(src, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\OPENCASCADE6.2.0\\ROS\\INC\\toptools_hsequenceofshape.hxx\n'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem?

shutil.copy(src,dst) should copy the file 'i' with the same basename to 'c:\directoryname' as long as the latter exists and is a directory.

Comment: the problem is with i that has the path which is read from the temp.txt file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a `\n` at the and of the filename.

Try:

```
copy(i.strip(), r"C:\opencascade")
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is single "\" rather than double "\" in the path.

Comment: Care to elaborate on this? Why does yesraaj need double backslashes?